# keras: figuring out calculation inside source for weight to input multiplication

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, collaborative-filtering

### Intuition:

I have created an [Autoencoder](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_denoising_autoencoder/) although it is for Rating Matrix for Users against Movies. I'm trying to recreate the output on prediction using Collaborative filtering (CF).

### The Dataset:

The dataset below is how the input goes in. I've converted it into a Pivot matrix here:
We'll call this **`A_set`**

```
MovieId 1    2    3    4    5    6    7  ...
UserId
0       5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  ...
1       0.0  0.0  0.0  2.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  ...
2       5.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...
3       1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  0.0  3.0  ...
```

The Transpose of this is also created, where `MovieIds` are in rows and `UserIds` in columns. We'll call this **`B_set`**.

### The Questionnaire:

Over this, I have the following queries:

- What set (A/B) can be called as Collaborative filtering (CF) on giving Input to Auto-encoder (made using Keras) in Neural Network?
- I'm trying to get a distinction on what part is User Based CF and Item Based CF
- Now I know internally, how the below formula works mathematically. I'm just not sure if it works the same way in Keras/TF code as well. Which one (set A/B) should I consider as my CF?

> Y = Theta(Transpose) . Input(X) + C

- Theta being the weight matrix, I need to see if the code transposes the Theta matrix and then solves the equation or is it already transposed and the input I give needs to be **`B_set`** to do justice to CF.

I tried giving **`A_set`** as input, and then also checked the weights after the input was trained / modeled. Check the Snippet:

```
w1 = model.get_weights()
train_set.shape # (5436, 3706)
w1[0].shape     # (3706, 529)
w1[0].T.shape   # (529, 3706)
w1[1].T.shape   # (529,)
w1[2].T.shape   # (264, 529)
w1[3].T.shape   # (264,)
w1[4].T.shape   # (132, 264)
w1[5].T.shape   # (132,)
w1[6].T.shape   # (264, 132)
w1[7].T.shape   # (264,)
w1[8].T.shape   # (529, 264)
w1[9].T.shape   # (529,)
w1[10].T.shape  # (3706, 529)
w1[11].T.shape  # (3706,)
```

Now it kind of makes sense, that this is probably being Transpose somewhere inside the Source code of Keras (please point me where!), else the Matrix multiplication would be impossible. Yet the question remains open as to which (set A/B) can be called as CF?